# Creating views on the fly from array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, nsmutablearray

I need to create a a bunch a views on the fly. I was wondering what would be the best way to go about doing this as ill need to define coordinates, tag, colours of each view.

Would i need to create a multidimensional array and if so how can i do this?

```
CGRect viewRect1 = { 80.0, 200.0, 160.0, 100.0 };
UIview *myview1 = [[UIview alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect1];
[myview1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a structure to hold the data which is needed to create your `UIView`.

```
@interface MyViewDataHolder :NSObject
{
     CGRect mViewRect;
     UIColor* mDarkGrayColor;
     NSInterger mTag;
}

@end
```

Then create an object of above class AND assign the values in member then add that in your `NSArray`...

**EDITED:**

**In MyViewDataHolder.h class**

```
@interface MyViewDataHolder :NSObject
{
    CGRect mViewRect;
    UIColor* mDarkGrayColor;
    NSInteger mTag;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) CGRect mViewRect;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIColor* mDarkGrayColor;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger mTag;

@end
```

**In MyViewDataHolder.mm class**

```
#import "MyViewDataHolder.h"


@implementation MyViewDataHolder

@synthesize mViewRect,mDarkGrayColor,mTag;

-(void) dealloc
{
    [mDarkGrayColor release]
    mDarkGrayColor = nil;
}
```

Now How to use it  ....

Create objects of `MyViewDataHolder` like below ...

```
MyViewDataHolder* myObj1 = [[MyViewDataHolder alloc] init];
myObj1.mViewRect = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
myObj1.tag = 1;
myObj1.mDarkGrayColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Create as much as you need

Then Create an `NSMutableArray` and add each objects of `MyViewDataHolder` into `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:myObj1];
[myArray addObject:myObj2];
[myArray addObject:myObj3];
and So on ....
```

When you need the stored info you could use as below ...

```
for(int index =0; index < [myArray count]; index++)
{

     MyViewDataHolder* myObj = (MyViewDataHolder*)[myArray objectAtIndex:index];
     myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myObj.mViewRect];
     //incriment x and y to refelect where you want your next view to be suituated 
     myView.tag = myObj.mTag; 
     myView.backgroundColor =  myObj.mDarkGrayColor;
     [self.view addSubview:myView];
     [myView release];
}
```

The code reflect the approach , Although  I didn't compile the code So use it as reference

Thanks ,

Comment: I dont know if you'll be able to elaborate on this, how would i use this to create n number of views. Ive been trying to understand how to create "structure" like objects before but ive always ended up going down the multidimensional array as it was easier

Comment: look forward to it, much appreciated.

Comment: thank you so much, this worked a treat. Spent all day trying to do what you've done. Thanks again.

Comment: @david-l; Glad to know it help you .

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to store your views in an array unless its just for pure convenience.

You can create a variable amount views using a for loop:

```
UIView *myView;
int x=0, y=0; 
int viewWidth = 50, viewHeight = 50;
for(int i=0; i<numberOFView; i++){
     myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,viewWidth,viewHeight)];
     //incriment x and y to refelect where you want your next view to be suituated 
     myView.tag = i+1; 
     [self.view addSubview:myView];
     [myView release];
}
```

Then to access each view in turn and carry out some work you can do the following:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews) {
    switch (view.tag) {
       case 1:
           //do something to the view 
           break;
       case 2:
           //do something to the view 
           break;
       case 3:
           //do something to the view
           break;
       //and so on...   
      default:
           break;
   }
}
```